# Como integrar meu Usuario ao xml do Spring Security

Tags: java-ee, jsf, primefaces, spring-security

Estou começando a aprender `Spring Security` e estou com algumas dúvidas. Antigamente eu fazia a autenticação de usuários usando `phaseListener`. Tenho o MB de Usuario onde o seu escopo é `@SessionScoped`. Como posso passar esse usuário e configura-lo nesse xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" security="none" />

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/Home.xhtml" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/suspensao/SuspensaoBegin.xhtml*" access="hasAnyRole('INICIO', 'ADMINISTRADORES')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/suspensao/SuspensaoMiddle.xhtml" access="hasAnyRole('MEIO', 'ADMINISTRADORES')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/suspensao/SuspensaoEnd.xhtml" access="hasAnyRole('FIM', 'ADMINISTRADORES')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="Diego" password="123" authorities="INICIO" />
                <user name="Joaquim" password="321" authorities="ADMINISTRADORES" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Resumindo, gostaria de passar Usuários dinamicamente para que eu consiga fazer o Login e Autenticação.

Comment: Você tem alguma classe que implementa a interface `AuthenticationProvider` ??

Comment: Ainda não, Tenho só o Usuario, UsuarioDAO e UsuarioBean e nenhuma delas implementa essa interface.